# Problema ao importar referência para o webservice do EZ Commerce

Tags: c#, genexus

Olá,

Gostaria de saber se alguém já importou diretamente pelo Genexus as definições para os webservices de integração com o EZ Commerce.

O meu problema é que os webservices do EZ Commerce exigem autenticação (ClientCredentials), e na opção WSDL Import do Genexus, não exibe tela para digitar o usuário e senha de autenticação.

No Visual Studio consigo adicionar a referência de serviço sem problemas, o próprio VS exibe a tela para informar as credenciais de autenticação.

Agradeço por qualquer ajuda.

Os detalhes do erro que me ocorre abaixo:

===================================

> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. (System)
>
> ------------------------------ Product = GeneXus 15 Version = 15.0.119728 U8
>
> ------------------------------ Program Location:
>
> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    at
> System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetNonFileStream(Uri uri, ICredentials
> credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)    at
> System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials
> credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)    at
> System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type
> ofObjectToReturn)    at
> System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.FinishInitUriString()    at
> System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl..ctor(String uriStr, XmlReaderSettings
> settings, XmlParserContext context, XmlResolver uriResolver)    at
> System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings.CreateReader(String inputUri,
> XmlParserContext inputContext)    at
> System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(String inputUri, XmlReaderSettings
> settings, XmlParserContext inputContext)    at
> Artech.GeneXus.Inspectors.WSDLInspectorDialog.getServiceReader(String
> url)    at
> Artech.GeneXus.Inspectors.WSDLInspectorDialog.LoadWebService(String
> url)    at
> Artech.GeneXus.Inspectors.WSDLInspectorDialog.inspectService(String
> url)
>
> ## Genexus

Comment: Tentou algum contato com o suporte do Genexus?

Comment: Olá Leandro. Sim, abrimos incidente pelo canal de suporte do Genexus hoje também.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jacson,

A melhor maneira, nesse caso, é salvar o wsdl em arquivo, pelo browser, e depois importar o arquivo pelo wsdl inspector.

De qualquer forma, você vai ter que alterar o código para relizar a autenticação, fazendo uso do tipo de dados location.

Vai ficar algo assim:
&Location = Getlocation([NomeDoObjetoExternoDoWsImportado])
&Location.user=&usuario
&Location.password=&password
&Webservice.metodo()

Comment: Olá Sandro, obrigado pelo retorno. Mais ou menos isso mesmo que o pessoal da Artech me passou.

Comment: Agradeço o feedback. Seria interessante marcar como resposta da pergunta, para ajudar outras pessoas que tenham a mesma dúvida.